# Picturebox+Imagem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Tenho um `Picturebox1` com uma imagem (cameras-hdv-merlin-cursos.png) exemplo:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Ao passar o mouse em cima dela gostaria que desse um efeito zoom,tipo isso entende.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O efeito em si é um pouco complicado, porém neste [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21097/PictureBox-Zoom) você já tem acesso ao código fonte bem detalhado de como implementar. Neste [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26532/A-Zoomable-and-Scrollable-PictureBox) também possui outro exemplo.

Você também pode considerar em criar uma nova instancia de bitmap:

```
Size newSize = new Size((int)(originalBitmap.Width * zoomFactor), (int)(originalBitmap.Height * zoomFactor));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(originalBitmap, newSize);
```

Só seguir os seguintes links que você vai conseguir.